# A better way to push and pop to/from lists in R?

Tags: r

If `foo <- list()`, I find myself writing `foo[[length(foo)+1]] <- bar` a lot when really I just want to write `push(foo, bar)`.

Similarly (though much less frequently) `bar <- foo[[length(foo)]]` would be much nicer as `bar <- pop(foo)`.

1. Is there a better way to do this in base R?
2. Failing that, has anyone written a package that makes these basic list operations less syntactically torturous?

It's the repetition of the variable name that kills me.  Consider:

```
anInformative.selfDocumenting.listName[[length(anInformative.selfDocumenting.listName)+1]] <- bar
```

---

edit:

`foo <- append(foo, bar)` doesn't work for me

```
foo <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  x <- data.frame(a=i, b=rnorm(1,0,1))
  foo[[length(foo)+1]] <- x
}
str(foo)
```

Gives a list of 10 objects as expected.

```
foo <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  x <- data.frame(a=i, b=rnorm(1,0,1))
  foo <- append(foo, x)
}
str(foo)
```

Gives a list of 20 objects.

Comment: No. `foo` is one object. If you append ten times with lists that are each length two then you get .... length 20

Comment: If you wanted one object which had ten data.frames you should have written `append(foo, list(x))`

Comment: It is not recommended in R to create growing lists. If you know the final length of your data, you should initialize it then populate it. If your data is numeric, you can even simplify into a matrix `matrix(NA, nrow=10, ncol=2)` then populate it.

Comment: RockScience - When would I expect to notice a difference between inserting into a pre-initialised list (I'm assuming you mean using something like `foo <- list()` and `length(foo) <- 10`) and an empty one?  Can you point me to a relevant reference indicating why it is not recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years late to the party, but here's the approach that requires the least amount of typing. Note that `pop` removes the last element from the object.

```
push <- function(obj, input) {
  variable <- deparse(substitute(obj))
  out <- get(variable, envir = parent.frame(n=2))
  out[[length(out)+1]] <- input
  assign(variable, out, envir = parent.frame(n=2))
}

pop <- function(obj) {
  variable <- deparse(substitute(obj))
  obj <- get(variable, envir = parent.frame(n=2))
  
  if (length(obj) > 0) {
    out <- obj[[length(obj)]]
    assign(variable, obj[-length(obj)], envir = parent.frame(n=2))
  }else{
    out <- NULL
    assign(variable, out, envir = parent.frame(n=2))
  }
  
  return(out)
}
```

Example:

```
> foo <- list()
> push(foo, "a")
> push(foo, "b")
> foo
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

> pop(foo)
[1] "b"
> foo
[[1]]
[1] "a"
```

Comment: This is a really good answer, and especially helpful for people like me coming from Python. It seems kind of bizarre that this isn't a builtin function.

Comment: @TarenSanders this answer fails to mention that mucking about with the global environment is akin to using goto statements. It's risky business. I agree that it's odd that there isn't an easy way to duplicate a list and then add to it (which I'd like `append` to do), but the design philosophy of R abjures functions that change their arguments.

Answer (score 18):

```
foo[[length(foo)+1]] <- bar
```

could be rewritten as

```
foo <- append(foo, bar)
```

and

```
bar <- foo[[length(foo)]]
```

could be rewritten as

```
bar <- tail(foo,1)
```

Note that with functional languages such as R functions generally aren't supposed to changes values of parameters passed to them; typically you return a new object which you can assign elsewhere. The function should have no "side effects." Functions like `push/pop` in other languages usually modify one of the passed parameters.

Comment: `append()` doesn't quite behave as desired, I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: Well, you didn't mention you were using data.frames. Try `foo <- append(foo, list(x))` instead. But really, your examples look like you should probably be using `lapply()` or some other function. Adding elements one-by-one in a for loop like that is very inefficient. For example: `foo<-lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame(a=i, b=rnorm(1,0,1)))`

Comment: When you say it is inefficient, are you talking about performance?  Can you explain a little more when or why using `lapply()` might be better than using a for loop?

Comment: Yes, code that adds elements one-by-one is often slower because you ned to keep reallocating memory as the collection grows. Using lapply to generate the list all at once is better since R will then know the total length of the new object and only allocate memory for it once.

Comment: Last paragraph nicely explains R in more depth - thanks :)

Comment: ... however, the `append(foo, bar)` isn't equivalent replacement for `foo[[length(foo)+1]] <- bar` if bar is a vector either. `foo <- append(foo, list(x))` is. You should edit your answer to reflect that.

Comment: `append` is a fragile solution that will _very frequently_ fail to add a single element to your list. (It's evidently designed for vectors.) You can usually append one list to another, but if you try to append a vector or matrix to a list, it appends each element of the vector separately instead. If you append a table, you add each columns separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
pushR = function(foo, bar){
  foo[[length(foo)+1]] <- bar
  foo
}

popR=function(foo){
  foo[[length(foo)]]
}

foo <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  x <- data.frame(a=i, b=rnorm(1,0,1))
  foo <- pushR(foo, x)
}

popR(foo)
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: It's perfectly obvious why the pushR function works--any comment would be less clear than the code.  But the 'pop' function doesn't modify foo, so it isn't a pop, and the test at the bottom could use a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  x <- data.frame(a=i, b=rnorm(1,0,1))
  foo[[length(foo)+1]] <- x
}
```

Can be written as:

```
foo <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
 x <- data.frame(a=i, b=rnorm(1,0,1))
 foo[[i]] <- x
}
```

if you are worried about repeating the variable names. I agree through that lapply works more efficiently, both in performance and length of your overall code.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and clean with closures

```
makeStack <- function() {
    valueList <- list()
    list(
        push = function(value) {
            valueList <<- append(valueList, value)
        },
        pop = function() {
            value <- utils::tail(valueList, 1)[[1]]
            valueList <<- utils::head(valueList, -1)
            value
        }
    )
}
```

```
> stack <- makeStack()
> stack$push(3)
> stack$push(5)
> stack$pop()
[1] 5
> stack$pop()
[1] 3
```